# Grant temporary read or read/write access to the directory to a particular user or all users without changing file/directory permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I've googled for it and found nothing. Any ideas how it can be achieved?

`mount -o bind,uid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0022` doesn't work - the original permissions are retained.

`mount -o bind,ro` will also **not** work because it will not allow to access inaccessible files/directories.

Comment: which filesystem is it?

Comment: @ilkkachu  Doesn't matter, we are talking about access to directories, not filesystems.

Comment: Directories aren't part of the filesystem? I think it does matter, because there's stuff like ACLs that not all filesystems support. Similarly, as far as I can read the man pages, `fmask`/`dmask` are specific to FAT-based filesystems. (Plus AFAIU they only remove / mask out permissions.)

Comment: It does not matter, period. I'm looking for a universal solution which I've already provided.

Comment: So you have a universal solution which does not work for one of the most popular distributions out there?

Comment: @Artem, well, you could specify that you want/need to be able to do it in a filesystem-independent way, if that's what you mean.

Comment: If something is **not** specified it could mean the person might be looking for a solution regardless of the underlying filesystem or your assumptions. And thank you for downvoting a **perfectly valid question**. *"I don't understand the issue at hand, I'm looking it from this angle and since it's not the angle the OP is interested in, the OP is wrong"*.

Comment: @doneal24  I don't care about distros which choose to circumvent decades all conventions like having the root user. And then you can run `sudo passwd root` in Ubuntu to get root back. It's amazing how no solutions are offered, yet I'm already being criticized.

Comment: @Artem, Yes, it could mean that. Or it could mean that the person isn't giving enough details about their constraints and the angle they're interested in. That's why I said it could be specified if there is a constraint of filesystem-independence (probably even "should"). If you're worried about downvotes you're getting, focusing on making your questions clear and answerable might work better than blindly blaming people commenting on them.

Comment: Again, if something which **you**'re personally interested in is not specified maybe it's because what you're looking for is not a concern for the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[bindfs](https://bindfs.org) is a FUSE filesystem for mounting a directory to another location, similarly to mount --bind. The permissions inside the mountpoint can be altered using various rules.

Comment: I'm curious why the question and a correct answer are being downvoted. If that's not what you're looking for, there's no need to downvote, please move along.